# htaccess mode rewrite rule not working on server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some url rewrites in my htaccess file all working fine on local but on server just rule for one page is causing issue (it is not working). Here is my htaccess rule

```
#allStroes
RewriteRule ^allstores?$ allstores.php [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^allstores/([^/.]+)/?$ allstores.php?type=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^allstores/([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/?$ allstores.php?type=$1&title=$2 [L,QSA]
```

am i doing something wrong ? Please help

Comment: the page is "allstores.php" it can be with type and title as params. i want it to be just "/allstores" or "allstores/type" or "allstores/type/title"

Comment: @anubhava rewrites for other pages are working fine . There might be some issue with my rule (but it is working fine on local machine).

Comment: yes question is for production. and htaccess is enabled there

Comment: yes ! `http://domain.com/allstores` is causing 404 . I have added random trash string in htaccess on server it gave 500. it means it is enabled there.

Comment: ok good, now can you show full .htaccess in question? Also tell location of this .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You might be forgetting to add

```
RewriteEngine On
```